# How to perform an ajax lookup within `ng-repeat`

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat of employees. One of the result fields returned is an employee number e.g. "12345".

How can I perform an ajax lookup and replace the employee number with the corresponding name?

Example: **/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('allStaff')/items?$select=fullName&$filter=userid eq '12345'**

would return: **"Doe, John".**

I've tried using a filter but nothing ever gets displayed even though I can see results returned.

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in employees"">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{emp.id}}
</div>

app.filter('getName', function($http) {
return function(id){

    if (id) {
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('allStaff')/items?$select=fullName&$filter=userid eq '"+id+"'";
        $http({  
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            cache: true,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            userInfo = data.d.results[0].pn;
            console.log(userInfo);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
            userInfo = "0";             
        });
        return userInfo;
    }
};
});
```

Comment: could you upload the code to jsfiddle ? I can't understand what you are trying to filter, may be paste the json from the _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('allStaff')/items?$select=fullName&$filter=userid eq '"+id+"'";

Comment: I cannot paste the results as it is company data. EMPID is a number and the returned result is their name e.g. 12345 would return "Doe, John".

Comment: @freeBSD I understand that you can't post company data but you can alter it all slightly so that it gives us the information we need without compromising security.

Answer (score 2):

The filter function is synchronous, while the `$http` call is asynchronous. The `success` callback isn't even going to be executed until after the filter function has already returned, so it looks like the return value will be `undefined`.

An angular filter isn't really appropriate for loading data from an API, and there's an easier approach. Add `userInfo` to the `employees` array in the appropriate service/factory/controller (that's up to how you're organizing your code, but the controller where you set `$scope.employees` is the quick and dirty option). Something like a `forEach` through the array making an API call for each one and setting `employee.userInfo` in the success callback:

```
app.controller('EmployeeController', function($scope, $http) {
    // $scope.employees is initialized somehow

    $scope.employees.forEach(function (employee) {
        if (employee.id) {
            var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('allStaff')/items?$select=fullName&$filter=userid eq '"+employee.id+"'";
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                cache: true,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            }).success(function (data) {
                employee.userInfo = data.d.results[0].pn;
            }).error(function () {
                employee.userInfo = "0";
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And in your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in employees">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{emp.userInfo}}
</div>
```

It's up to you to figure out what to do before the ajax request is finished, while `emp.userInfo` is undefined - hide the element, show a placeholder, etc.

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to an example? This is a bit bewildering to me.